# import a unity file into a already made Xcode file

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a Xcode file with some stuff halfway done, and I want to include a unity file into it without restarting my progress so I can use the unity file in my already-made Xcode project. Is there any way to achieve this? I know theres a tutorial here https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing) but this requires me to restart my project and I can't keep my progress.

Sorry the language is very clumsy because my English isn't that good

Comment: What do you mean by "unity file"?

Comment: Unity projects don't compile into human-usable xcode projects.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that turning the unity project into Xcode like the tutorial above and merging those two Xcode files together